# start docker toolbox from windows .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, docker, docker-toolbox

I have installed Docker Toolbox on my Windows machine.

so when I need to start some Docker containers I:

1. I start the Docker terminal (which starts the Docker virtual machine
2. I use `cd` to command to go to the dir where I have some specific `docker-compose.yml` file
3. I start the container using `docker-compose up -d`

can I have all of this in a `.bat` file so I just click and don't lose time typing the same everytime I need to start the container?

Comment: Yes, put all the commands that you would put into cmd into a .bat file and run it and fix whatever errors until it does what you want....

Comment: I can start the terminal, but dont know how to execute commands inside the terminal

Answer (score 2):

Create a .bat file with following content:

```
@echo off 
setlocal 
"%GIT_INSTALL_ROOT%\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "%DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH%\start.sh" 
"%PROJECT_LOCATION%/yourDockerComposeCommandsHere.sh
```

And the yourDockerComposeCommandsHere.sh file with commands you would like to run.

e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $PROJECT_LOCATION
docker-compose up -d ...
docker-compose up -d ...
docker-compose up -d ...
```

Do not forget to setup environment variables: GIT_INSTALL_ROOT, DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH, PROJECT_LOCATION.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a batch file starting the start.sh with full path, but that didn't work.

This worked for me: Given that Docker toolbox installed in C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox, try the below procedure:

Put all these commands in a file called "Docker.cmd" on your desktop and run it as administrator.

```
cd\
cd "Program Files"
cd "Docker Toolbox"
start.sh
```